# Adjusting shell mode color schemes

Tags: shell, emacs, colors, themes

The color schemes in emacs shell mode appear as primary colors (high saturation) and look primitive,  and some colors, for example, purple, do not appear:

[image]

I want to adjust the colors so that they use more intermediate colors and look more soft as in gnome-terminal:

[image]

How can I change the color schemes in shell mode? I couldn't find shell-mode related font assignments in emacs, and that is probably because the color is given by the shell and is different from other font assignmets in emacs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When a program run inside shell-mode issues ANSI escape characters to set the display color to, say, magenta, Emacs intercepts those escape characters and creates a colored overlay using that exact foreground color "magenta". So there's no color theme interaction going on here, and no shell-specific customizations to look for.

The interception is made by the functions in `ansi-color.el`, though, and it looks like you could customize `ansi-color-names-vector`, so to use "PaleBlue" for "blue", either `M-x customize RET ansi-color-names-vector`, or try putting something like the following in your emacs config:

```
(setq ansi-color-names-vector
  ["black" "red" "green" "yellow" "PaleBlue" "magenta" "cyan" "white"])
```

To see available color names, use `M-x list-colors-display`, or enter hex colors instead, e.g. "#ccccff".

Comment: Thank you. This worked. It solved a problem that I had for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Some [color-themes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) are designed to look good in the terminal. If none of them suit, you could use one a starting point for your own theme. I select the appropriate theme for X/terminal like this:

```
(if (eq (window-system) 'x)
    (color-theme-gray30)
    (color-theme-emacs-nw))
```

Comment: I think you are thinking of runing emacs in terminal. That is not what I am asking. I am running a terminal in emacs.